# iphone tab bar icon click area

Tags: iphone, icons, tabbar

Do the sizes of the tab bar icons determine the clickable area? If I have a smaller tab bar icon, does that make the clickable area smaller?

Answer (score 3):

No, the tab bar is always the same size. The buttons get horizontally smaller as you add more, but the height never changes, nor does the clickable area. Always 44px.